# Text into Date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When importing data from Magento to Google Sheets, the date of each transaction is in text format.

For example:

```
1.1.2020 14.54.16

31.12.2019 16.17.32
```

How can I format the date part into value? The time of the day should be eliminated.

Desired output:

```
43830

43831
```

Test sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IyGzzrWQMeM-FbV3TVBl23V0NTKq7aWfuf88DKnQwwQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: what do the numbers in the desired output represent

Comment: Numerical value of the date.

Comment: how to get from 1.1.2020 to 43830?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) 
The Time component can be extracted using REGEXTRACT function, as I have placed it in the test sheet

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2, "(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}.\d{4,4})")
```

2)replace . with *

=SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","*")

3)Split on *

```
=SPLIT(C2,"*")
```

4)Create Date Object

```
=DATE(F2, E2, D2)
```

5)Convert to Numerical

```
=DATEVALUE(G2)
```

Comment: Hi Ian! Thanks for the input. However, that's not what I'm trying to achieve. Your suggestion is in a text format and that is what I'm trying to get rid of.

The output should be in a number format because that's how I'd able to change it to any date format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD or DD-MM-YYYY) I prefer.

Comment: so you want to make a date object from the text is that correct?

Comment: Try edited solution. See test sheet. Although I still don't understand google's numerical value of date :P

Comment: As a pointer, Google's numerical value of a date is computed as the number of days starting on `1900-1-1`.